# How to install J2EE web application in clustered environment?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere

How to install J2EE web application in clustered environment?
Currently using IBM websphere application server to deploy my code.

Comment: What is your question about? Applications are deployed to clustered WAS the same way they are deployed to non-clustered one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically is the same process as when you install the application in your local application server.

The only difference is that you have to map the application to the cluster in step tagged as **"Map modules to servers"**, that is select the cluster from the select-box, check the application check-box the application and click **Apply**.